# NHibernate: receiving index out of range while calling flush for insert operation

Tags: nhibernate, insert, flush

I've spent the better part of my day trying to solve this message while using NHibernate: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

My update and delete work just fine but the call to flush after a call to save() does not work. I don't think it will be useful to post all of the code (there's a lot) because I'm not sure what you'll need to see at this point. My data access object I'm trying to save uses a composite key if that helps. Also, I'm using NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes to create my mapping.

It appears that in my stack trace NHibernate is attempting to send an invalid number of parameters to the ADO.Net class for the insert operation. That being said, I have trace set to true in order to view sql statements but the error is raised prior to the sql statement being sent to the output so I'm not sure what it's attempting to build..

```
public void Insert(ProddataDAO Entity)
{
        Entity.PSEQ = GetNewSeqID(Entity.PCUST); // <- because I'm using a composite key, this function gets my a unique value by a group
        NHibernateHelperCGC.CurrentSession.Save(Entity);            
        NHibernateHelperCGC.CurrentSession.Flush();   // <-This raises the error         
}
```

> at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)    at
>   IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2ParameterCollection.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32
>   index)    at NHibernate.Type.DecimalType.Set(IDbCommand st, Object
>   value, Int32 index)    at
>   NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, Object value,
>   Int32 index)    at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand
>   st, Object value, Int32 index, ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Type.ComponentType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value,
>   Int32 begin, ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object
>   id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty,
>   Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement,
>   ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index)    at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id,
>   Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql,
>   Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id,
>   Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute()    at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)    at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)    at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource
>   session)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent
>   event)    at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()    at
>   WTS.Data.DB2.CGC.ProddataRepository.Insert(ProddataDAO Entity) in
>   C:\Documents and Settings\briant\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\WTSCGCDAL\WTSCGCDAL\ProddataRepository.cs:line 73    at
>   WTS.WTSCGCAppInterface.ProductionDataUserControlBase.TestInsert() in
>   C:\Documents and Settings\briant\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\WTSCGCAppInterface\WTSCGCAppInterface\ProductionDataUserControlBase.cs:line
>   483    at WTSCGCAppInterface.Window1.Button_Click_1(Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\briant\My
>   Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\WTSCGCAppInterface\WTSCGCAppInterface\Window1.xaml.cs:line
>   48    at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object
>   target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs
>   e)    at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object
>   sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
>   target)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
>   RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.CrackMouseButtonEventAndReRaiseEvent(DependencyObject
>   sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender,
>   MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
>   target)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
>   RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
>   trusted)    at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() 
>   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs
>   input)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
>   inputReport)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd,
>   InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x,
>   Int32 y, Int32 wheel)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate
>   catchHandler)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback,
>   Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean
>   isSingleParameter)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, Delegate method, Object arg)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr
>   wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()    at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run()    at WTSCGCAppInterface.App.Main()
>   in C:\Documents and Settings\briant\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\WTSCGCAppInterface\WTSCGCAppInterface\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line
>   0    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[]
>   args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error usually appears when there are columns missing from your tables. So if a class has a property mapped to table column that is missing from the database then you will see this error.

Basically check for mismatches between your mappings and your database tables (missing columns, type mismatches etc). The problem may be on a related table/entity and not on the one you are trying to save.

Comment: Someone responded in another post that I had two extra mapping attributes. One for property and another as keyed so I'll give you the point for being close.

Answer (score 1):

I had also this problem and after hours of googling, I found out that was a problem in the mapping: I had a column with the same `name` twice (in my case it was both a `<key-property>` , as part of a `<composite-id>`, and also a column in the `<many-to-one>` element. I solved changing `<key-property>` to `<key-many-to-one>` and deleting the `<many-to-one>` element).

Comment: Instead of posting the same answer to multiple questions, you should flag questions as duplicates.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that!

Comment: I see you can't do that yet, because you haven't reached 50 reputation yet, but it shouldn't take too long.